# Jenkins can not recognize spring EL？

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

My java project uses `local.properties` to set environment. My `local.properties` contents are:

`tsHome=/opt/test/ts`.

It can work in windows, but when I run test in Jenkins, I output the `tsHome`. It shows `${tsHome}`. It seems Jenkins can not recognize it, why?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO]. Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].